# Determining the actual file name sent when using Send Port Macros

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a BizTalk 2009 send port that uses the %datetime_bts2000% macro in the file name.  When I look at the tracked message event, I don't get the name of the actual file that was sent.  I thought I could get it from the context property:

OutboundTransportLocation
SFTP://xxx@xxxx.xxx.com:22/Inbound/Encrypted/xxx.xxx.xxx.**201101280410324**
Promoted
http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties

It turns out that the date is equivalent to my deployment date... not the actual date time stamp of the sent file.

Where do I find the actual filename generated by the Macro?

Comment: What SFTP send adapter are you using?  Or this is with the file adapter?

Comment: nSoftware's SFTP Adapter.  I have the same issue with the Microsoft provided File Send Adapter as well.

Comment: I've always made sure I set these manually in my own pipeline comp to guarantee its in the context.  I cannot remember which macro I was using but I found something similar a few years ago.  When in doubt, roll your own.

Comment: Bryan, you probably used the %SourceFileName% macro. Christian, if you set the FILE.ReceivedFileName context property either in a Receive Pipeline with custom component or set it in an Orcherstration and use the %SourceFileName% macro then you can see the ReceivedFileName in the Context Properties of the message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happen to agree with @Bryan.  I have in fact created such a pipeline to preserve OR set the attachment file name explicitly in a pipeline that I use for email.